# How does URL::to work in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have made an installation of laravel in a subfolder.

e.g.

`foo.com/laravel/`

now all calls to

foo.com/ are directed to a different application.

All calls to for example

foo.com/laravel/baz are directed to laravel

the routes still look like this

`Route::get('/baz', function(){...});`

and it works

The sublinks, when using `URL::to` in these routes in blades, works too.

`URL::to` does not work in e-mails though

for example when doing this in an e-mail:

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/baz')}}">bippo</a>
```

the resulting url is to

`foo.com/baz` and not to `foo.com/laravel/baz`

this leads to my question, how does `URL::to` work, and how can I make it work the way I want? e.g. to always return the URL to the root of the installation.

Comment: You can make a helper and define your own `urlTo($param)` and inside redirect with laravel url. I can write an example if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php` for details but in short - Laravel's URL generator relies on Request object (current web request) and in the case of email there is no web request whatsoever.

That's why you don't see `/laravel` prefix – there is no way it could be known in that context.

Easy workaround is to define 'url' in config/app.php and prefix URLs with config('app.url') instead of using url() helper or URL facade. At least in emails (but perhaps everywhere).

In sum, this is not Laravel's problem, it's more related to the nature of web requests/HTTP protocol.

Comment: actually I think laravel has a predefined config for this the `env('APP_URL')`

Answer (score 0):

URL::to() works like this in the below link.
https://medium.com/@zwacky/laravels-url-to-vs-url-asset-fd427ed6f7ef#.ktwxwdjxz

https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*xD1x7OeXU5NNGwfKWsvpcw.png

check for yourself.

It takes the route in the to() function and checks for it to be the valid route in routes file and then creates a functional route for the same.
And for the question you asked, I don't know why would you even want to do that? If you elaborate what you want to achieve, maybe we could help.